# Does code generator that generates presentation level witn MVVM pattern exists?

Tags: c#, wpf, code-generation, model-view

Does code generator that generates presentation level with model view view model pattern exists ?
I need a generator that will generate code with presentation level for widnows desktop or WPF application all with data binding using MVVM pattern (from database or object model)

Does something like that exists ?

Comment: CodeFluent Entities should do the job

Answer (score 0):

You can use T4 Templates to do this. If you want learn about T4 template, I recommend you read [T4 Tutorial: Creating reusable code generation templates](http://www.olegsych.com/2008/09/t4-tutorial-creating-reusable-code-generation-templates/).